# build.gradle file error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've tried to add a library to android studio
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Quick-Setup

and after compiling I get the
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:appcombat-v7:22.2.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcombat-v7/22.2.0/appcombat-v7-22.2.0.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcombat-v7/22.2.0/appcombat-v7-22.2.0.jar
>            file:/Users/sergiumereuta/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcombat-v7/22.2.0/appcombat-v7-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/Users/sergiumereuta/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcombat-v7/22.2.0/appcombat-v7-22.2.0.jar
>            file:/Users/sergiumereuta/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcombat-v7/22.2.0/appcombat-v7-22.2.0.pom
>            file:/Users/sergiumereuta/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcombat-v7/22.2.0/appcombat-v7-22.2.0.jar
>        Required by:
>            XMLParsingTest:app:unspecified

can anybody help me to solve the problem? thanks!
here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sergiumereuta.xmlparsingtest"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcombat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Typo. Replace your app compact dependency for:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

Should be appcompat and not appcombat

Answer (score 1):

Try Cleaning the project and Rebuilding it again.

```
In Build => Clean Project then 
        Rebuilt Project.
```

Then sync again.
It should work, reply if problem continue

Ya Sandro Machado is correct .

```
You should replace appcombat to appcompat
```